# Datatable click on td or a (link) inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I'm using datatable, and I like to know, when I click inside the table, if the click is made on a(link) or td(cell).

```
<td>
    my text - <a href="mylink.html">mylink</a>
</td>
```

This is my datatable initialisation

```
oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable(
{
...
};
```

And my check on td click

```
oTable.on("click", 'td', function(e)
{
...
});
```

Actually, I have the same result `(this)`, if I click on td or a.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `e.target` is your friend

Comment: haim770 thanks , this the answer, but can you give it as an answer, not as comment, to permit me to validate the answer ?

Comment: Thanks. I think your own answer is already doing the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to haim770 quick tips, I found how to solve my problem

The [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property returns the DOM element, so I can retrieve property/attribute that has a value.

The [`event.target.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) property is meant specifically for *element nodes* (type 1 nodes) to get the type of *element*.

Otherwise [other types of nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) are available (comment, attribute, text, etc.). To get the name of the node types, I use the [`nodeName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName).

When using `nodeName` against an *element node*, I'll get its tag name, so either could really be used, though I'll get [better consistency between browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23) when using `nodeName`.

In my case I'll have to use to get a href URl link:

```
oTable.on("click", 'td', function(e)
{
    var $a = $(this).children('a');
    var contactUrl = $a.attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch click on `a` inside `td` you should use :

```
oTable.on("click", 'td a', function(e)
{
...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry but this is not my question, I like to catch click on <a> who is inside a <td> and click on <td> too. See my html example. dataTable init working well.

Comment: e.target is the answer, cant validate your repose